# Conditional Formatting in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to format Text.

```
Text("Hello")
.foregroundColor(self.amount > 20 ? .blue : .white)
```

How would you add another condition say:

```
if self.amount > 100 and self.amount > 200
```

and so on?

Comment: You can add a computed property in the same struct, but outside of the `var body` property like so: `var textColorBasedOnAmount: Color { if amount <= 20 { return .white } else if amount < 40 { return .blue } else { return .red } }` etc and the in your body `Text(“Hello”).foreGroundColor(self.textColorBasedOnAmount)`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't add more than 2 parameters to a ternary `?` operator. But you could do this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello")
        .foregroundColor(amount > 100 ? .red : amount > 20 ? .blue : .white)
}
```

Or You will have to use the normal `if else` statements like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    if self.amount > 200 {
        return Text("Hello")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    } else if self.amount > 100 {
        return Text("Hello")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    } else {
        return Text("Hello")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not about `Swift.print`, it is about `SwiftUI.Text` which is a View

Comment: Surely you can chain the conditional operator, e.g. `amount > 100 ? .red : amount > 20 ? .blue : .white`

Comment: Thanks.. this worked... the key I figured was making sure to do them in correct order...  if I did `amount > 20 ? .red `first.... then  `amount  > 100 ? .blue` .... everything was turning red over 20 ..  once I switched the conditions around it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the solutions above and had success with the answer by @Sajjon provided in the comments. I wanted to repost it here as a helpful alternative solution.

```
var textColor: Color { 
   if amount <= 20 { 
      return .white 
   } else if amount < 40 { 
      return .blue 
   } else { 
      return .red 
   } 
}
```

Then in the body

```
Text(“Hello”)
   .foreGroundColor(self.textColor)
```